# Do I have to rebuild my app for every iOS new version release to make it available at the AppStore?

Tags: ios, xcode, release, ios15

I think this is not required, at my personal experience only new iOS specific features in my application will require a new release, but a personal client is asking me to confirm this.

With every new XCode release, do I have to rebuild and publish my application in order to make it available at the AppStore of new iOS Release?

If there is any official documentation that proves this will be appreciated!

Comment: No need. I'd test the app with iOS15 though, just in case of API breaking change, but usually you should be fine... Test also you app compiling with new iOS15 and run it from XCode to prepare future changes (it's better to do them now when they can be minor than two years from now where you'd might have plenty and plenty of modifications to do).

Comment: Thanks for the information @Larme, Do you think this could be a problem?
[Community reported error iOS 15](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682775)
[Code Signature Format](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/using-the-latest-code-signature-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to re-publish. Apps remain in the App Store until the developer pulls it (or very rarely, Apple pulls it due to policy violations).

There is likely not any documentation that explicitly states this, but consider a scenario where somebody gets the new iPhone 13 and opts to restore it from iCloud. Data is pulled from iCloud, but apps are restored by re-installing them from the App Store. If apps disappeared from the App Store because they haven't been re-compiled, then anybody who upgraded their phone would discover that a large number of their apps had disappeared.

Anecdotally, my company has apps in the App Store that haven't seen a new submission in over 2 years (since iOS 12). Those apps are still in the store.

Answer (score 1):

You can test your iOS app using the new Xcode 13 and if you got some bug using the new iOS SDK, you can fix it and submit a new version to App Store using the new Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Its prudent to test your apps on each new OS (preferably before the public release) but in most cases no new release is necessary.  Over time you may want to update your app to take advantage of new features or to better support new devices.  No app will never last forever but you will likely be able to go some time before having to update.